# NUnit test a method that call another method inside the same class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Let's say I have a class with a method, that call another method doing some transformation as private action on input parameters:

```
public void DoWork(params object[] arguments)
{
   DoWorkSuper(Transform(arguments));
}

public void DoWorkSuper(string item)
{
}

private string Transform(params object[] arguments) {}
```

What I want to test is that `DoWorkSuper()` was called on object with the proper parameter and as side effect test `Transform` method. There is no external dependencies so mock framework most probably won't solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don´t even see any problem. When you want to check thet `DoWorkSuper` is called from`DoWork` you surely have to execute the latter, which will execute `Transform`.

Comment: *"...and as side effect test Transform method."* -  don't do that. Don't test two things at once. if you want to check the correctness of `Transform` then, you might want to extract it to a "Strategy" class and test it separately.